# Replacing last two characters in PySpark column

Tags: python, pyspark

In a spark dataframe with a column containing date-based integers (like 20190200, 20180900), I would like to replace all those ending on 00 to end on 01, so that I can convert them afterwards to readable timestamps.

I have the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

udf = sf.udf(lambda x: x.replace("00","01"), StringType())

sdf.withColumn('date_k', udf(sf.col("date_k"))).show()
```

I also tried:

```
sdf.withColumn('date_k',sf.regexp_replace(sf.col('date_k').cast('string').substr(1, 9),'00','01'))
```

The problem is this doesn't work when having for instance a value of 20200100, as it will produce 20201101.

I tried also with `'\\00', '01'` , it does not work. What is the right way to use this regex for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. you can use `$` to identify string ending `00` and use `regexp_replace` to replace it with `01`

```
    # Input DF
    df.show(truncate=False)

    # +--------+
    # |value   |
    # +--------+
    # |20190200|
    # |20180900|
    # |20200100|
    # |20200176|
    # +--------+

    df.withColumn("value", F.col('value').cast( StringType()))\
        .withColumn("value", F.when(F.col('value').rlike("(00$)"), F.regexp_replace(F.col('value'),r'(00$)','01')).otherwise(F.col('value'))).show()


    # +--------+
    # |   value|
    # +--------+
    # |20190201|
    # |20180901|
    # |20200101|
    # |20200176|
    # +--------
```

Comment: This worked in my Own case,  where i had a Data Pipeline with wrongly formatted sizes like   0,6 l     which needed to be 0.6 l.   My code was to first replace the last ' l' with ' l.' then finally replaced the comma with '.' using
 regexp_replace.withColumn("ProductSize2", F.regexp_replace(
                        F.when(F.col("ProductSize").rlike('( l$)'),
                       F.regexp_replace(F.col("ProductSize"),r'( l$)',' l.')).otherwise(F.col('ProductSize'))  
                                             ,",",".")

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it.
Explanation first cut the number for first part excluding last two digits and in second do regex replace, then concat both parts.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df = spark.sql("""
select 20200100 as date
union
select 20311100 as date
""")

df.show()
"""
+--------+
|    date|
+--------+
|20311100|
|20200100|
+--------+
"""

df.withColumn("date_k", f.expr("""concat(substring(cast(date as string), 0,length(date)-2),
                               regexp_replace(substring(cast(date as string), length(date)-1,length(date)),'00','01'))""")).show()


"""
+--------+--------+
|    date|  date_k|
+--------+--------+
|20311100|20311101|
|20200100|20200101|
+--------+--------+

"""
```